# Sikuli How to Use "while not" with "and not"

Tags: sikuli

I've been trying to program my Sikuli bot to find a certain item on Google's webpage results, and then if it doesn't find either of two different things, then it needs to refresh the page.

What I've got is:

```
while not exists("1613966501287.png") and not exists("1613966531551.png"):
        click("1613905413870.png")
        wait(3)

//click(<image>) is to click the refresh button.
```

So far, it has been able to detect both of the images I'm asking to find and then refresh the page if it can't, so I'm assuming I've done something wrong with my logic of using while/not/and.

Comment: Hello Zemroda, Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is vague. When exactly does your code fail?

Answer (score 0):

The current code will wait until one of the two images appear. In other words the 'while' loop will continue until bot images are not present on the screen.

Comment: Hi, the wording of the second sentence makes it incorrect. It'll continue until either image is present on the screen—the reasoning might be clearer if you apply de Morgan's rule. (Also—I think you meant 'both', not 'bot'.)

Comment: So, basically, I'm wanting my bot to find this item link on Google's webpage results in blue text, or potentially purple if I've already clicked on it, so I need it to check if the either the blue or purple link is on the screen, if not, I want it to continuously loop pressing the "refresh" button until one of the items appears, once it does, it will then click the link with another "if exists(png)" line.

Comment: After checking, it appears I hadn't taken a Sikuli screenshot that was big enough for it to detect the item accurately, so I made a slightly large one by making a bigger box around the link when in screenshot mode.

So far it seems to work perfectly now that I did that.